# Evaluar en JS input type="file" y convertirlo en Blob

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un formulario y dentro de el input type=file y lo quiero mandar por el .ajax a php que a su vez conecta a mi base de datos.

Todos los datos me ingresan correctos pero no logro convertir input type=file a BLOB, solo me guarda la fakepath como texto creo, pero no el archivo y necesito es el BLOB del archivo.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="imagen1" class="form-control-file border " name="file">
```

JS

```
var form1 = document.getElementById("formularioproyectos");

form1.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    var imagenes1 = document.getElementById('imagen1');
    var extencionss = imagenes1.value;
    console.log(extencionss);//me devuelve la URL u NO el BLOB

   if (1==1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Datos guardados con exito");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../modelos/modeloformulario.php',
            data: { "imgsst":extencionss},
            beforesend: () => { $("#resultado2").html("Espere un momento...") },
            success: (respuesta) => { $("#resultado2").html(respuesta) }
        })   
}
})
```

PHP

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$imgsst=$_POST['imgsst'];//deberiaresivir el BLOB
```

No se como evaluar para que tener los datos del archivo BLOB

```
var imagenes1 = document.getElementById('imagen1') ???.value . file .?
```

Comment: Los datos del archivo te refieres por ejemplo:  File `{name: "check.png", lastModified: 1526392401541, lastModifiedDate: Tue May 15 2018 08:53:21 GMT-0500 (hora de verano central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 3513, …}` ' ??

Comment: No, creo que escribí mal disculpa, cuando digo datos me refiero a la cadena de caracteres de genera el  blob

Comment: @DiegoMolina puede que [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11156/subida-de-im%c3%a1genes-por-ajax-mediante-phpmysql) te ayude a solucionarlo de otra forma. ¿Si o si tiene que enviarse como `BLOB`?

Answer (score 0):

```
function crearBase64(archivoAConvertir) {

   var resultado = "";

   var r = new FileReader();
   r.readAsDataURL(archivoAConvertir);
   r.onload = function () {
     resultado = r.result;
   };
   r.onerror = function(error) {
     console.log('Ocurrio un error: ', error);
   };

   return resultado;
}

var archivo = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];
var base64 = crearBase64(archivo);

console.log(base64); //Imprime la cadena del archivo en base 64
```

Comment: 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.  casi casi, pero me arroja esto :(