# Problemas al generar una imagen en PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Compañeros buen día.
Solicito de su ayuda con este inconveniente,mediante un formulario grabo en la BD el nombre, nombre_imagen pero resulta que el archivo me sale en formato no válido, creo que estoy confundido o estoy mal interpretando el concepto con respecto a la conversión base64 (Imagenes).
Adunto mi código.

**Consulta para guardar los registros**
Funciona Correctamente.

```
switch($opcion){
    case "regusu":
        //code neccesary
        $usuario = str_replace(' ','+',$_POST["usuario"]);
        $usuario = $usuario.".jpg";
        $query_insert_tb_images = "INSERT INTO tb_imagenes(nombre_imagen)VALUES('".$usuario."')";
        $result_images = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_insert_tb_images);
        $id_images = mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
        if($result_images){
            $query_insert_tb_usuarios = "INSERT INTO tb_usuarios(nombre,cod_imagen)VALUES('".$_POST["usuario"]."','".$id_images."')";
            $result_images = mysqli_query($conexion, $query_insert_tb_usuarios);
            if($result_images){
                echo "";
            }else{
                echo "";
            }
        }
    break;
```

**Aquí es mi problema**
Código para que la imagen se guarde en el directorio
**JS**

```
$("#btn_reg_usu").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
    var imagen =$('input[type=file]').val()
    $.ajax({
        url: "./subir.php",
        method: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        data: {"opcion": "savimg","usuario":usuario,"usuario_imagen":imagen},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            //response = JSON.parse(response);
            if(response){
                toastr.success("IMAGEN REGISTRADO", "IMAGEN PERFIL");
            }else{
                toastr.error("IMAGEN NO REGISTRADO", "IMAGEN PERFIL");
            }
        }
    });//end ajax
});
```

**PHP**

```
case "savimg": 
    $nombre_imagen = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
    $imagen = $_REQUEST['usuario_imagen'];

    $imagen = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$imagen);
    $imagen = str_replace(' ','+',$imagen);
    $data = base64_decode($imagen);
    file_put_contents('./images/'.$nombre_imagen.'.jpg', $data);
    
    if(is_file( './images'.$nombre_imagen.'.jpg')){
     echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
break;
```

No me da ningún error en el codigo, pero el archivo me lo guarda así
[image: imagen]

Comment: pregunta del millon, en el php estas seguro que estas recibiendo el archivo en formato texto, si haces un var_dump($imagen); que optienes??

Comment: Estimado, me sale esto: string(21) "C:\fakepath\tokio.jpg" false

Comment: entonces lo que estas recibiendo es un archivo, no un string base64...

Comment: inténtalo como esta aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/14486/46896

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Subida de imágenes por ajax mediante php+mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11156/subida-de-im%c3%a1genes-por-ajax-mediante-phpmysql)